# How to update a dependent variable for -lm- in a loop if a condition is met

Tags: r, for-loop, regression

I am trying to run a regression and have it run if dummy/binary variable takes a value of 1. I have a set of 5 dummy variables and want 5 regressions that all have the same dependent variable: Y|d1==1 ~ x1 + x2, Y|d2==1 ~ x1 + x2. I have the following minimal working example:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  x2 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  Y = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  d1 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T),
  d2 = sample(0:1, 10000, replace=T)
)

n <- 2
regList <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
names(regList) <- c("first", "second")

for(i in seq_along(regList)){
  regList[[i]] <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x2, df)
}
```

I am unsure what to do to "update" the dependent variable. I was thinking of using:

```r
form <- update(form, ...)
```

in the loop before the -lm- part but unsure how to use it properly.
I am rather new to this. Anything would help, I could not find a similar enough question and if i have missed it please let me know. I just have "Y" at the beginning of -lm- but that, rather obviously, just gave me the same output n times. Not sure how to implement an if function or a way to stratify it. I want to use the same Y in the data frame but only if that particular dummy variable contains a 1 or if I can use the original string variable and regress Y on X* if string=="name".

Comment: I have updated it accordingly, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: One thing to mention, in my true dataset d1 and d2 are mutually exclusive--I don't know how to include this in my working example as I generated random dummy variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this scenario, you don't really need to change your formula, you need to filter the data you are passing in to your regression. You could do something like

```
n <- 2
regList <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)    
for(i in seq_along(regList)){
  regList[[i]] <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x2, df[df[[paste0("d", i)]]==1, ])
}
```

Here we subset `df` to just the rows where `d1` or `d2` are 1 for each respective iteration.

Comment: I get an error: "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases". Im going to update my code so it reflects my actual scenario more as I think it may be slightly different now

Comment: Ah I see why, the dummy variables in my above example are conveniently d1 and d2. In my actual work they have names that aren't related by number (they have names wheat, maize, rice, soybean, rapeseed) is there a workaround where I can create a list and run it through that? But yes the above does work I just forgot to clear my environment. I will update the code!

Comment: @Brennan instead of the seq_along, just use a vector of column names. And use lapply rather than a loop so you don’t have to worry about indexing the result list.

Comment: I will look into it, I am quite new to this so don't even know what lapply is. I will accept the answer as it works for the example I gave, thank you very much!